# Cache Proxy Server Returning 404 with www.google.com

Tags: python, caching, networking, proxy

I have a homework assignment which involves implementing a proxy cache server in Python for web pages. Here is my implementation of it

```
from socket import *
import sys

def main():
    #Create a server socket, bind it to a port and start listening
    tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #Initializing socket
    tcpSerSock.bind(("", 8030)) #Binding socket to port
    tcpSerSock.listen(5) #Listening for page requests
    while True:
        #Start receiving data from the client
        print 'Ready to serve...'
        tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
        print 'Received a connection from:', addr
        message = tcpCliSock.recv(1024)
        print message

        #Extract the filename from the given message
        filename = ""
        try:
            filename = message.split()[1].partition("/")[2].replace("/", "")
        except:
            continue
        fileExist = False

        try: #Check whether the file exists in the cache
            f = open(filename, "r")
            outputdata = f.readlines()
            fileExist = True
            #ProxyServer finds a cache hit and generates a response message
            tcpCliSock.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n")
            tcpCliSock.send("Content-Type:text/html\r\n")
            for data in outputdata:
                tcpCliSock.send(data)
            print 'Read from cache'
        except IOError: #Error handling for file not found in cache
            if fileExist == False:

                c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #Create a socket on the proxyserver

                try:
                    srv = getaddrinfo(filename, 80)
                    c.connect((filename, 80)) #https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html
                    # Create a temporary file on this socket and ask port 80 for
                    # the file requested by the client
                    fileobj = c.makefile('r', 0)
                    fileobj.write("GET " + "http://" + filename + " HTTP/1.0\r\n")
                    # Read the response into buffer
                    buffr = fileobj.readlines()
                    # Create a new file in the cache for the requested file.
                    # Also send the response in the buffer to client socket and the
                    # corresponding file in the cache
                    tmpFile = open(filename,"wb")
                    for data in buffr:
                        tmpFile.write(data)
                        tcpCliSock.send(data)
                except:
                    print "Illegal request"
            else: #File not found
                print "404: File Not Found"
        tcpCliSock.close() #Close the client and the server sockets

main()
```

I configured my browsers to use my proxy server like so

[image]

But my problem when I run it is that no matter what web page I try to access it returns a 404 error with the initial connection and then a connection reset error with subsequent connections. I have no idea why so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you use strings for booleans? Why not e.g. `fileExist = False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a number of issues with your code.

Your URL parser is quite cumbersome. Instead of the line

```
filename = message.split()[1].partition("/")[2].replace("/", "")
```

I would use

```
import re
parsed_url = re.match(r'GET\s+http://(([^/]+)(.*))\sHTTP/1.*$', message)
local_path = parsed_url.group(3)
host_name = parsed_url.group(2)
filename = parsed_url.group(1)
```

If you catch an exception there, you should probably throw an error because it is a request your proxy doesn't understand (e.g. a POST).

When you assemble your request to the destination server, you then use

```
fileobj.write("GET {object} HTTP/1.0\n".format(object=local_path))
fileobj.write("Host: {host}\n\n".format(host=host_name))
```

You should also include some of the header lines from the original request because they can make a major difference to the returned content.

Furthermore, you currently cache the entire response with all header lines, so you should not add your own when serving from cache.

What you have doesn't work, anyway, because there is no guarantee that you will get a 200 and `text/html` content. You should check the response code and only cache if you did indeed get a 200.